# Python Tkinter check radio button state before proceed

Tags: python, tkinter

I have this code which is working

```
import Tkinter as tk
from Tkinter import *


LARGE_FONT= ("Verdana", 12)

class ChangePages(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack()
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.frames = {}
        for F in (MainPage, Page01, Page02):

            frame = F(container, self)

            self.frames[F] = frame

            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame(MainPage)

    def show_frame(self, cont):

        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()

#MainPage
class MainPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)

        button1=Button(self,text='Go To Page 1',fg='blue',font=('Helvetica',26),height=5, width=20,command=lambda: controller.show_frame(Page01)).grid(row=1,column=1)

#Page01
class Page01(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):

        option1 = IntVar()
        option2 = IntVar()
        option3 = IntVar()

        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        f = Frame(self)
        f.pack(side='left')

        label1=Label(f,text='Select options',fg='blue', font=("Arial", 36, "bold"),width=54, relief='solid').grid(row=1,column=1,columnspan=3)

        labelspacing=Label(f,text='Option 1 ',font=("Arial", 18, "bold"),width=20,height=1).grid(row=2,column=1)
        labelspacing=Label(f,text='Option 2 ',font=("Arial", 18, "bold"),width=20,height=1).grid(row=2,column=2)
        labelspacing=Label(f,text='Option 3',font=("Arial", 18, "bold"),width=20,height=1).grid(row=2,column=3)

        buttonoption11=Radiobutton(f, text="Option 1 - A", variable=option1, value=1, indicatoron=0, fg='blue',font=('Helvetica',26),height=1, width=20).grid(row=3,column=1)
        buttonoption21=Radiobutton(f, text="Option 2 - A", variable=option2, value=1, indicatoron=0, fg='blue',font=('Helvetica',26),height=1, width=20).grid(row=3,column=2)
        buttonoption31=Radiobutton(f, text="Option 3 - A", variable=option3, value=1, indicatoron=0, fg='blue',font=('Helvetica',26),height=1, width=20).grid(row=3,column=3)

        buttonoption12=Radiobutton(f, text="Option 1 - B", variable=option1, value=2, indicatoron=0, fg='blue',font=('Helvetica',26),height=1, width=20).grid(row=4,column=1)
        buttonoption22=Radiobutton(f, text="Option 2 - B", variable=option2, value=2, indicatoron=0, fg='blue',font=('Helvetica',26),height=1, width=20).grid(row=4,column=2)
        buttonoption32=Radiobutton(f, text="Option 3 - B", variable=option3, value=2, indicatoron=0, fg='blue',font=('Helvetica',26),height=1, width=20).grid(row=4,column=3)

        buttonoption23=Radiobutton(f, text="Option 2 - C", variable=option2, value=3, indicatoron=0, fg='blue',font=('Helvetica',26),height=1, width=20).grid(row=5,column=2)

        buttonnback=Button(f,text='Back',fg='blue',font=('Helvetica',26),height=1,width=15,command=lambda: controller.show_frame(MainPage)).grid(row=10,column=1)
        buttonnext=Button(f,text='Next',fg='blue',font=('Helvetica',26),height=3,width=15,command=lambda: controller.show_frame(Page02)).grid(row=10,column=2)

#Page02
class Page02(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Page 02!!!", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)

        button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Back to Home",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(MainPage))
        button1.pack()

        button2 = tk.Button(self, text="Page 01",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageSub35t))
        button2.pack()


#Root loop
app = ChangePages()
app.mainloop()
```

What I want to do is:

When the user presses next in pag01, I want to check the states of radio buttons. For example if the user chose "Option 1 -A" and "Option 2 -C", I want to popup a message saying "You are not allowed to choose 2c! You can choose 2c only if 1B is selected" and not let him to go to page02.

Comment: Why have you struggled to implement this so far? What have you tried to do?

Comment: Grammar and spelling

Answer (score 0):

I understand your problem and how you want to solve it. But, from an user experience point of view there is a better way of doing this. Instead of showing the user options that the user can't choose and displaying error messages, it is better to **only show the user what he can choose**. Scenario example:

> User selected Option 1 -A
>
> The Radio button Option 2 -C turns grey(disabled)

Here is a demo:

```
#very bad code
#http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28900100/python-tkinter-check-radio-button-state-before-proceed/28901595#28901595

try:#3.X
    import tkinter as tk
except ImportError:#2.X
    import Tkinter as tk

#use ttk cascade style techniques instead !!!
LARGE_FONT= ("Verdana", 12)

class ChangePages(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack() #use grid everywhere
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.frames = {}
        for F in (MainPage, Page01, Page02):

            frame = F(container, self)

            self.frames[F] = frame

            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame(MainPage)

    def show_frame(self, cont):

        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()

class MainPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)

        button1 = tk.Button(self,text='Go To Page 1',fg='blue',font=('Helvetica',26),height=5, width=20,command=lambda: controller.show_frame(Page01)).grid(row=1,column=1)

class Page01(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):

        option1 = tk.IntVar()
        option2 = tk.IntVar()
        option3 = tk.IntVar()

        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        f = tk.Frame(self)
        f.pack(side='left')

        label1 = tk.Label(f,text='Select options',fg='blue', font=("Arial", 36, "bold"),width=54, relief='solid').grid(row=1,column=1,columnspan=3)

        #not used
        #labelspacing = tk.Label(f,text='Option 1 ',font=("Arial", 18, "bold"),width=20,height=1).grid(row=2,column=1)
        #labelspacing = tk.Label(f,text='Option 2 ',font=("Arial", 18, "bold"),width=20,height=1).grid(row=2,column=2)
        #labelspacing = tk.Label(f,text='Option 3',font=("Arial", 18, "bold"),width=20,height=1).grid(row=2,column=3)

        buttonoption21 = tk.Radiobutton(f, text="Option 2 - A", variable=option2, value=1, indicatoron=0, fg='blue',font=('Helvetica',26),height=1, width=20)
        buttonoption21.grid(row=3,column=2)
        buttonoption22 = tk.Radiobutton(f, text="Option 2 - B", variable=option2, value=2, indicatoron=0, fg='blue',font=('Helvetica',26),height=1, width=20)
        buttonoption22.grid(row=4,column=2)
        buttonoption32 = tk.Radiobutton(f, text="Option 3 - B", variable=option3, value=2, indicatoron=0, fg='blue',font=('Helvetica',26),height=1, width=20)
        buttonoption32.grid(row=4,column=3)

        buttonoption23 = tk.Radiobutton(f, text="Option 2 - C", variable=option2, value=3, indicatoron=0, fg='blue',font=('Helvetica',26),height=1, width=20)
        buttonoption23.grid(row=5,column=2)

        # this entire list is affected by switch_all_button()
        list_conditional = [buttonoption21, buttonoption22, buttonoption32, buttonoption23]


        def switch_button(button, active=True):
            if button is not None:
                button['state'] = {True: tk.NORMAL, False: tk.DISABLED}[active]
                #here you can also unselect

        def switch_all_button(active=True):
            for button in list_conditional:
                switch_button(button, active=active)

        def after_option_command(what_button_should_be_disabled=None):
            def after_option():
                switch_all_button(active=True)
                switch_button(what_button_should_be_disabled, active=False)
            return after_option


        # to update the state of other buttons after 1 is pressed
        # use command=after_option_command(button_x) in the constructor
        buttonoption11 = tk.Radiobutton(f, command=after_option_command(buttonoption23), text="Option 1 - A", variable=option1, value=1, indicatoron=0, fg='blue',font=('Helvetica',26),height=1, width=20)
        buttonoption11.grid(row=3,column=1)
        buttonoption12 = tk.Radiobutton(f, command=after_option_command(), text="Option 1 - B", variable=option1, value=2, indicatoron=0, fg='blue',font=('Helvetica',26),height=1, width=20)
        buttonoption12.grid(row=4,column=1)



        buttonnback = tk.Button(f,text='Back',fg='blue',font=('Helvetica',26),height=1,width=15,command=lambda: controller.show_frame(MainPage)).grid(row=10,column=1)
        buttonnext = tk.Button(f,text='Next',fg='blue',font=('Helvetica',26),height=3,width=15,command=lambda: controller.show_frame(Page02)).grid(row=10,column=2)

class Page02(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Page 02!!!", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)

        button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Back to Home",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(MainPage))
        button1.pack()

        button2 = tk.Button(self, text="Page 01",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageSub35t))
        button2.pack()


#Root loop
app = ChangePages()
app.mainloop()
```

You don't need to import tkinter twice. Use this syntax

```
try:  # 3.X
    import tkinter as tk
except ImportError:  # 2.X
    import Tkinter as tk
```

will force you to use `tk.` every time you are using a tkinter object explicit better than implicit. It will also work with Python 3.

```
#Page02
class Page02(tk.Frame):
```

this is a useless comment because it doesn't add value.
The code is poor quality, but here's how to fix it:

- Follow PEP8
- Do not use classes as keys for dicts
- Instead of describing the look inside your main code, do it outside or on top of the file using `ttk` and `ttk.Style()`
- Widget.grid method returns None, which means

  `buttonoption11 = tk.Radiobutton(f, command=after_option_command(buttonoption23), text="Option 1 - A", variable=option1, value=1, indicatoron=0, fg='blue',font=('Helvetica',26),height=1, width=20).grid(row=3,column=1)`

  - buttonoption11  is not a `tk.Radiobutton` but `None`
  - use .grid everywhere unless you have a very good reason not to
  - use for loops to create similar widgets

**Warning** the code I gave is not fixed, do not use it before you apply all tips given above

edit: works as expected in the comment, read the comments to extend the API

Comment: First of all thanks a lot for the answer. Second, if i press first on option 1a , then option 2c became inactive which is right, but if then i press option 1b, option2c remain inactive till i do some clicks on options2.. can i fix this somehow? thanks again